# Safari Mobile (Ipad) doesn't seem to cache my telerik and Microsoft CDN resource files used by my aspx page

Tags: performance, asp.net-ajax, telerik, mobile-safari, http-caching

I have an aspx web page with various Telerik RadControls on it and each time this page is loaded, Safari mobile seems to download all the resource files again - for example the following files are downloaded on each page request to an ipad - nothing seems to get cached as it would be on other non-mobile browsers.

```
http://aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/ajaxz/2010.3.1109/Common/Navigation/NavigationScripts.js
http://aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/ajaxz/2010.3.1109/PanelBar/RadPanelBarScripts.js
http://aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/ajaxz/2010.3.1109/Input/TextBox/RadInputScript.js
http://aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/ajaxz/2010.3.1109/ListBox/RadListBoxScripts.js
http://aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/ajaxz/2010.3.1109/ComboBox/RadComboBoxScripts.js
http://aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/ajaxz/2010.3.1109/Grid/RadGridScripts.js
```

This is over 100K of javascript being passed down each time even though the CDN resources are set to cache and have ETAGS.

I've rigged up fiddler to both the ipad and a laptop running IE/FF/Safari each time the laptop browser is caching the resource files above and the ipad isn't.

I think this is why my app performs notably slower on the Ipad although it may be the slow javascipt parsing on the Ipad as well...

Has anyone else had this problem? Am i missing something obvious here?

Thanks.

EDIT

I am monitoring the iPad traffic on the laptop by making the laptop an http proxy for the iPad.

**Extra Info from fiddler:**

Fiddler v2.3.0.0, laptop results from IE8, iPad vers. 3.2.2.

From my laptop, If I go to http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

and after click "First Look" a few times the following in in fiddler:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host        URL                         Body    Caching     Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
1   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    54,608  private     text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:6172           
2   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8  iexplore:6172           
4   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    54,608  private     text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:6172           
5   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8  iexplore:6172           
7   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    54,608  private     text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:6172           
8   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8  iexplore:6172           
10  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    54,608  private     text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:6172           
11  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8  iexplore:6172
```

If I do the same on my iPad the following is recorded by fiddler:

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL                             Body    Caching     Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
1   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    54,380  private     text/html; charset=utf-8                
2   200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/Common/Navigation/NavigationScripts.js   7,856   public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
3   200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ComboBox/RadComboBoxScripts.js   16,238  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
4   200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/Ajax/Ajax.js 7,509   public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
5   200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ToolBar/RadToolBarScripts.js 13,372  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
6   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8              
8   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    54,380  private     text/html; charset=utf-8                
9   200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/Common/Navigation/NavigationScripts.js   7,856   public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
10  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ComboBox/RadComboBoxScripts.js   16,238  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
11  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ListBox/RadListBoxScripts.js 13,199  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
12  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8              
13  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ToolBar/RadToolBarScripts.js 13,372  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
15  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    54,380  private     text/html; charset=utf-8                
16  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/Common/Navigation/NavigationScripts.js   7,856   public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
17  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ComboBox/RadComboBoxScripts.js   16,238  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
18  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ToolBar/RadToolBarScripts.js 13,372  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
19  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/ListBox/RadListBoxScripts.js 13,199  public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
20  200 HTTP    aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com    /ajaxz/2010.3.1317/Ajax/Ajax.js 7,509   public, max-age=31536000  Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2021 15:05:25 GMT    application/x-javascript                
21  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

EDIT 2:

I have tried exactly the same test as above again today and noticed that:

1) The IPad **is now** caching the javascript

2) Telerik demos **are not using the CDN** but they were yesterday! (see results below compared to results above)

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host        URL                         Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
1   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    53,036  private     text/html; charset=utf-8                
2   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2010.3.1317.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a9506cff2-3a86-46c5-b869-6ba1478f3c27%3a1c2121e%3ae8945d51%3af4636213%3ac531f12c%3a4d471440%3af7131199%3ac17ca3a3  10,599  public, max-age=31533429  Expires: Sat, 18 Feb 2012 10:06:39 GMT    text/css                
3   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a8f393b2b-3315-402f-b504-cd6d2db001f6%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a9506cff2-3a86-46c5-b869-6ba1478f3c27%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a24ee1bba%3af46195d3%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a628ebdd0%3a9cdfc6e7%3aed16cbdc%3a2bef5fcc%3aa7e79140   160,387 public, max-age=31533429  Expires: Sat, 18 Feb 2012 10:06:40 GMT    application/x-javascript                
4   200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8              
10  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    53,032  private     text/html; charset=utf-8                
11  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8              
14  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    53,032  private     text/html; charset=utf-8                
15  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8              
18  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx    53,032  private     text/html; charset=utf-8                
19  200 HTTP    demos.telerik.com   /aspnet-ajax/Common/CodeViewer.js.aspx  5,534   private     text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested it with Fiddler - opened a RadListBox on a page with version 2010.3.1109 on an iPad (iOS 4.2) and it seems to me the CDN resources are cached properly and are not refreshed from the CDN every time as you are experiencing.

Can you share some more details about this issue, like a sample page or a live URL where we can test it? You can open a support ticket in your Telerik account to send those if you prefer the privacy.

EDIT:

I've also tested with 3.2.2 and I still can't reproduce this issue. Are you using some specific iPad settings or network setup worth mentioning?

Comment: Yep, I tested the online demos of the telerik AJAX controls on IPad (which have CDN enabled) and confirm that the resources are cached as expected.

Comment: thanks for looking at this - i expect i'm doing something daft - i've included an example in my question for you to look at. thanks.

Comment: Hi bundyo, could it be that I've setup the laptop as the http proxy for the iPad and setup fiddler to monitor remote connections on the laptop. This is the only way i know to monitor the ipad traffic with fiddler.

Comment: Well, I've done the same and it seems to be working, so probably not.

Comment: Ok well I will test on a friends iPad and with a differnet proxy and report back here. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No problem.

Meanwhile I've stumbled across an article which states that the iPhone's Mobile Safari cache is way too small and doesn't cache files with uncompressed size less than 15KB:
http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/

The article is for iPhone, though there are several references across the web which state that the iPad's Safari cache is the same size. The strange thing is why then my and Dick Lampards' requests are cached. 
We will need to look more into this issue. Thank you for bringing it up.

Comment: I've updated the original question with results - seems like the telerik demo site is not using the CDN today and now my iPad is caching the axd's.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this - we transitioned the demos to a different server and it seems CDN support was switched off in the process. We'll see to get it enabled again.

Comment: I've checked and CDN support is working - it doesn't work the first time the page is opened when it checks if the CDN can be accessed and sets a cookie for that. While the cookie exists (it has an 1 day lifespan) CDN is used.

Comment: I've refactored my web page to remove the reliance on so many js libs - ajax.net / jquery / telerik and controltoolkit controls - just too much! I still can't get the telerik demo site to serve from a CDN but I've tested again on my site with an empty ipad cache and it seems to be just the radgridscripts.js which won't cache - maybe it's the size? 57k (310k uncompressed)

Comment: Yes, it should be due to its size. I've tested mostly with RadListBox which scripts tend to be much smaller in size and they got cached.

Comment: Ok. Well it seems that by clearing the safari browser cache regularly and by refactoring my code slightly then there is a certain amount of caching going on - not great though. Lets call it poor design - partly by me and partly by Apple. Thanks for the help.